# breeze entityAspect has a null entityManager & entityGroup properties

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, breeze, entity-framework-6, durandal

Pretty run of the mill code, overlooking something. After the user selects a listing, I load Listing.js view and the listing from breeze. After the call in Listing.js the results come back with entities that have entityAspect but the entityAspect has null entityManager & entityGroup, as well as all subsequent calls. So I'm losing the manager somehow, when I refresh @ the Listing.js view, the entities are fine and everything works.

Listings.js:

```
self.selectListing = function (listing) {
            //window.location = '#listings/' + listing.listingID() +'/listingFields' <--Same results as below
            self.router.navigate('#listings/' + listing.listingID() +'/listingFields');
    };
```

Listing.js

```
self.activate = function (id) {
        return dataservice.listing.getListingById(id).then(function (data) {
            self.listing(data.results[0]);
            self.router.reset();
            self.router.makeRelative({
                moduleId: 'listings',
                route: 'listings/:id'
            }).map([
            { route: 'listingFields', title: 'Text Fields', moduleId: 'listingFields/listingFields', hash: '#listings/' + id + '/listingFields', nav: true },
            { route: 'collateral', title: 'Collateral', moduleId: 'collateral/collateral', hash: '#listings/' + id + '/collateral', nav: true }
            ]).buildNavigationModel();
        });
    };
```

[image: Null entityManager]

Comment: Is it possible you are doing a full page refresh somehow and losing your entityManager?  Doesn't make a ton of sense but it's possible I guess?

Comment: I don't think so, as the shell.js or anything else higher doesn't get called again.  That's whats troubling, I do this elsewhere in the app without issue. Thanks though, I going to double check that anyway.

Comment: Or there might be a possibility that you are making new instance of EntityManager.. You can check for the same..

Comment: So I'm using durandal to pass a singleton:
    define(['plugins/router', 'durandal/app', 'services/dataservice'], function (router, app, dataservice)
And I only new up a manager in the datacontext.js once.  But thats where I get lost.  My guess is durandal is not passing my dataservice to the new page incorrectly, or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So. Dont be a dummy and forget that you're doing this: datacontext.manager.clearUnchanged(); on viewModel deactivate.